# 2 Apache instances running. Can both access mariaDB?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, mariadb

I have 2 Apache2 instances running on my server ( Debian.)

One called Apache2 (ports 80,443,4443)
One called apache2-suiteCRM (port 8443)

The second instance is created to install suiteCRM and the problem there is that I get an error "can not load DB manager". I can run the install and all preliminary checks are ok, I have setup a database and a user with all privileges. But one way or another it seems that this Apache instance can not access the mariaDB database. My only guess is that it is because it runs on a second instance.

Is there some simple code to check if my server on port 8443 can read and write into mariaDB?

Thanks

Comment: I can't think of a reason why 2 Apaches would have trouble.  I have seen _many_ instances from _different_ servers work fine.  Apache sends a message to MySQL, which then replies to the sender.  Look for more clues.  Is it connecting via "localhost"?  Or TCP/IP?

Comment: The connection is going through localhost. I set it as localhost and as IP 127.0.1.2 which is set in hosts.

Comment: I think those are inconsistent.

Comment: The thing is there was already set 127.0.0.1 for ncp webportal, 127.0.1.1 for nextcloud. So I have set 127.0.1.2 for suiteCRM. I am a newbie, but that made sense to me and so far both Apache servers are running and suiteCRM loads on the webpage, the prerequisites check run fine, but on the final configuration page when click next it hangs on can not load DB manager. See https://community.suitecrm.com/t/cannot-load-db-manager-2-apache-servers-instances-mariadb-debian/77687. I described it there as well with database results.

Comment: "localhost" implies going through a socket.  An IP address implies going through TCP/IP.  Try going to the IP address of the host you are own.

Comment: The magical tool for these problems are logs. [These values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) in `php.ini` configure error reporting of PHP. I would set `display_errors = On` in a development environment.

Comment: @ Rick James. Could you be a little more specific on this explanation. Specifically about the IP address that I should own. Some example perhaps? Thx